# Eclipse Error: no jogl in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

So I'm quite new to eclipse (first week of actually trying to use it to develop stuff.) and I tried to import an example project from http://unfoldingmaps.org/ and upon trying to compile their test project I'm greeted with the error:

Eclipse Error: Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path

Right now my $path sys var looks like this:

```
    C:\csvn\Python25\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 6.0\bin; %JAVA_HOME%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

Is there something that I'm missing?   Jogl.jar is in the project but it seems like the project is just skipping over stuff.. help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your application requires some sort of native library, you need to specify the parameter -Djava.library.path=/path/to/libs on the VM args field on eclipse.

Comment: I actually found the answer just before you answered this, but this is very close to correct.

Comment: Just for others, who stumble upon this: We describe how to set this up in the first paragraph of our Unfolding for Eclipse tutorial. http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/getting-started-in-eclipse.html